# How to select different visualizations with buttons

Tags: carto

I have created a few visualizations in cartodb, and I'm trying to create a html with some buttons to select each one.

I have seen some examples using createlayer and sublayers, but not using different viz.jon.

I am a rookie, and I would like that someone to give me a simple example to start developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing something, but you could simply have different buttons that trigger `createVis()` for different `vis.json` files

One hangup may be removing existing visualizations when a new button is clicked. The code here does this in a brute force way with a [jQuery $.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) on `#map`. There may be a built in CartoDB method for this (?) not sure. Have not tested any of this...

**html**

```
<button data-url="http://account.cartodb.com/yourvis1.json">vis #1</button>
<button data-url="http://account.cartodb.com/yourvis2.json">vis #2</button>
<button data-url="http://account.cartodb.com/yourvis3.json">vis #3</button>
```

**javascript/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        $('#map').empty();
        var url = $(this).data().url;
        cartodb.createVis('map', url);
    });
});
```